# How to access google map through google map API in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I Have downloaded the google map library from GitHub and added it in to my libraries in Codigniter. After that I have loaded this library to the controller:

```
  $this->load->library('googlemaps');
```

and then:

```
  $this->googlemaps->initialize();
  $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

After that I have added this in my view:

```
  <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
  <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
```

But something is wrong when I am trying to access the Google Map.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "But something went wrong when i am trying access the google map.": Please show us your error. What went wrong? You didn't tell us the most important part of your question.

Comment: Sorry For That but i got it. Actually i forgot to add Api Key.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add marker in google map